# Grails: Multiple Relationships between same two Objects

Tags: grails

How do I define a relationship like the following: 
A person can belong to many projects. A person can be the technical contact for a project or, they can be the business contact for a project or they can be both. If the person gets deleted the project doesn't get deleted. If a project gets deleted the person doesn't get deleted.

```
class Project { 
  String name
  Person technicalContact
  Person businessContact

  static constraints = {
  }
}

class Person {
  String firstName 
  String lastName
  String email
  String phone
  String department

  static constraints = {
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @danf working on formatting. Sorry I forgot example earlier.

Comment: Take a look at many-to-many mapping in Grails domain.
[link](https://grails.org/wiki/Many-to-Many%20Mapping%20without%20Hibernate%20XML)

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 **one-to-many** in one table like this

```
class Project { 
  String name
}

class Person {
  String firstName 
  String lastName
  String email
  String phone
  String department

  static hasMany = [technicalContactForProjects: Project ,
                  businessContactForProjects: Project 
]
}
```

Grails will automatically make 2 relation table from that 2 **hasMany**, so you can delete its relation without delete the actual person or project.